# Does the 10-day self-quarantine upon arrival in the Netherlands include the day of arrival?

Tags: covid-19, netherlands, quarantine

According to the [official Dutch guidelines](https://www.government.nl/topics/coronavirus-covid-19/visiting-the-netherlands-from-abroad/self-quarantine), one must quarantine for 10 days immediately on arrival to the Netherlands from abroad. Does this 10-day period include the day of arrival?

To be more specific, suppose the day of arrival is 31st January, then does the 10-day self-quarantine end on 9th February or 10th February?

I tried looking through the official website of the Dutch Government, but I couldn’t find clear answers. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. January 31 would be day 1 and February  9 would be day 10.

Your quarantine obligation no longer exists on February 10.

The government has an official website concerning travel and quarantine measures according to your travel plan/history at https://reizentijdenscorona.rijksoverheid.nl/, including the possibility to shorten the quarantine with an additional test on day 5 or after.

Comment: The calendar item generated by the website is named "31 januari 2021 t/m 10 februari 2021" which suggests you're still supposed to stay home on the 10th. The rest of the page is not very specific about that but it does ensure that even someone travelling on the evening of the 31st spent 10 full 24-hour periods in isolation.

Comment: @Relaxed Although it also says in the timeline "Mogelijk klachten
Tot en met dag 10" and on https://www.rijksoverheid.nl/onderwerpen/coronavirus-covid-19/reizen-en-vakantie/in-thuisquarantaine-bij-aankomst-in-nederland it says "Wees wel extra voorzichtig en vermijd kwetsbare mensen tot en met dag 10." I'll send a question to the government.